# JPA Criteria (and JPQL) right outer join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entities A,B the relation is on way, optional, One-To-Many from A to B (the many side), I want to select  each B and its related A (or in case there is no A related to that B I want null), that can be easily done with right outer join but the problem that hibernate doesn't support right outer join in criteria API so I want a work around for this.

Comment: It's not possible to perform joins using the `Criteria` API if the association isn't modelled in the direction you're navigating. You could try using HQL and writing an ANSI-89 join equivalent of the right outer join you want (hoping the RDBM's optimizer will effectively perform a join).

Comment: I decided not to use Criteria API for this and just use JPQL "select b,a from A a RIGHT JOIN a.lotsOfBs b"

Answer (score 2):

As per your scenario you want to use left join. like

```
select b from B b left join A a 
where a.fkey is null
```

or if you want any criteria before join then use

```
select b from B b left join A a with a.type = 1
where a.fkey is null
```

this with will server similar purpose which is served with "and" with "on" clause

example:

```
select t from Template t left join t.profiles p with p.type = 1
where p.id is null
```

This will get all templates having no profiles with type 1